# Reducing query execution time using INDEX in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with four millions of records. Say, **PP_Product_Cost** with primary key **PP_Product_Cost_ID**. From My java application, the common selection WHERE clauses are *Costelement_ID, Order_ID, Product_ID, acctSchema_ID*.

A select query say, `select * from PP_Order_Cost where Costelement_ID=1000003 AND Order_ID=1000006 AND Product_ID=1001851 AND acctSchema_ID=1000003` is taking *2500 milliseconds* to execute. 
I need to reduce the execution time. There is no **INDEX** for this table.

Can I reduce the execution time using proper Indexing? If YES how can I properly add INDEX for this table?
(The WHERE clause columns are not unique as itself or by combination)

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field(s) used in a decision context, e.g. join, where, group by, order by, etc... should have an index on it.

Comment: So I shall add the 'CREATE INDEX... USING btree..' for Costelement_ID, Order_ID, Product_ID, acctSchema_ID. Is it so?

Comment: depends on how/where you're going to use those fields in other queries. one 'big' index of all the fields, or multiple smaller indexes of single or a few of the fields - you'll have to decide. but you want the indexes to be as "universally useful" as possible.

Comment: Thank you @MarcB. There are several indexing methods in postgres - **B-tree, Hash, GiST and GIN**. Which is more useful in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE INDEX ix ON PP_Order_Cost(Costelement_ID, Order_ID, Product_ID, acctSchema_ID)`

This should reduce the execution time of your query to a nominal time.   Whether the index is worth supporting this one query is your call...

Comment: Thats great. The time has reduced to ~50 milliseconds. Most of my WHERE clause combinations are these four(Costelement_ID, Order_ID, Product_ID, acctSchema_ID). If I need to **add some more filtering parameters** or **reduce some parameters** from this four, do any drastic change in execution time?

Comment: Index elements can only be used from left to right, so the index I specified is precisely tailored to the one query you presented   (i.e. a query that specifies the Order_ID without the Costelment_ID will not be able to make use of it).   You may want to add some more indexes to these filter/join columns.    When you add indexes, you're trading off query times against the increased disk usage and update times required for the record (each index needs to be updated on each record insert, or on relevent record updates).    (one more comment below)

Comment: As for whether you might want to add additional terms to the index to support filtering, it really depends on how many records are potentially left once the four IDs in the index are specified).    If it's less than 20 or 30, I probably wouldn't bother.    But do understand that the SQL engine must retrieve and inspect every record that contains filtering criteria that are not present in the index it uses.

Comment: Thank you very much @Curt. Can you suggest some good documents regarding the memory usage of the Index mechanism in DB. If we are using more number of indexes, is it consume RAM/Cache? If YES how can we control it?

Comment: Ram/cache won't be increased (that's an engine setting), but the bigger each index entry, and the more indexes you have, the lower the likelihood that the index page you need will be found in cache, which will lead to more disk reads, and lower performance.     I would suggest reading any book on a database engine design or performance optimization (it doesn't have to be for Postgres, necessarily, as the issues are the same for all engines).